# Where is ComboBox popup in visual tree?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, visual-tree

Where in the visual tree can I find the ComboBox popup (the list with the ComboBoxItems)?

I have programmatically opened a ComboBox and when watching it in the WPF Tree Visualizer in the debugger I see the following:

```
: ComboBox
  templateRoot : Grid
    PART_Popup : Popup
    toggleButton : ToggleButton
      templateRoot : Border
        splitBorder : Border
          Arrow : Path
    contentPresenter : ContentPresenter
      : TextBlock
```

I expected to see a ScrollViewer with some kind of item host (StackPanel?), perhaps where the PART_Popup is, but nothing.

So where is it?

Comment: `Popup` will have its own visual tree

Comment: Its own tree, meaning that the ComboBox and the Popup does not have a shared root?

Comment: Yes, when you set `IsOpen=true` new visual tree is created. You can read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018(v=vs.110).aspx) page under _Popup and Visual Tree_. Current visual tree and `Popup` are connected via `Popup.PlacementTarget`. You can use it to get to main visual tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PART_Popup does have StackPanel with ItemsHost set to True and wrapped around by ScrollViewer. You can check out the default template here at [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This is how it looks like:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup"
       Placement="Bottom"
       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
       AllowsTransparency="True"
       Focusable="False"
       PopupAnimation="Slide">
    <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
      <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
              BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Border.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
        </Border.Background>
      </Border>
      <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

---

**UPDATE**

PopUp and comboBox doesn't share the same root. **They belong to different Visual Tree**, that's why not visible in WPF Tree Visualizer since PopUp needs to be opened to see it's Visual Tree.

You can use [**Snoop**](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) which is WPF spying utility which also has feature to inspect Visual Tree. Snapshot taken from Snoop for popup looks like this *(Windows 8)*:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the Popup is found in the `ControlTemplate`, in a Grid together with the `ToggleButton` and seleced item's `ContentPresenter`. So why can't I see it in the visual tree?

Comment: Found it, thanks. I actually started with Snoop, but whenever my application loses focus (when I switch to Snoop) the popup disappears :(