# ComboBox background windows 10 wpf

Tags: wpf

How can I give background color for ComboBox in windows 10?

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxError" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF8888"></Setter>
</Style>

cmbPlayer.Style = Resources("ComboBoxError")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to actually find the comboboxes' popup from it's default template and set the background on that.

This [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx) from microsoft shows the make up of a combo box and this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088824/where-is-combobox-popup-in-visual-tree) shows where it is in the visual tree.